# internationalized domain name -> UnknownHostException

Tags: java, dns, internationalization, diacritics

In Germany, we have sometimes a mutated vowel (umlaut) in domain names.
its a part of the `internationalized domain name (IDN)`, such as `tile.öpnvkarte.de`.

If I try to download a Tile from there, java throws a `java.net.UnknownHostException: tile.öpnvkarte.de`.

Does somebody know how I can solve that?

Comment: Could you share with us some code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should first convert the IDN name to punycode using the `toASCII` method in [`java.net.IDN`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/IDN.html) before trying to resolve it.